# How to remove trailing whitespace and carriage return characters?

Tags: substitute

My goal is to get rid of "bad" CRs and trailing spaces at once, so I am executing the following command:

```
:%s/^M\|\s\+$//g
```

The problem is that if at the end of the line there is a `^M` and trailing spaces, only the `^M` is removed.

Is there a way to replace both parts of the OR expression on the same time?

Comment: John, I felt the question's title sounded a bit too general so I took the liberty and changed it. Feel free to [edit] and change to something you like better.

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? If one of the solution solves your problem maybe could you accept it using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do:

```
:%s/\s*^M\?$//g
```

Where:

- `\?` is for optional
- `^M` is inserted using <kbd>Ctrl v</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Wait a second... without the `$` in the pattern, you'll remove all whitespace anywhere or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks @Friedrich, well done :-) I have corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've had an autocmd that clears trailing white spaces on write, for a long time now in my `~/.vimrc`

```
autocmd BufWritePre * :%s/\s\+$//e
```

This might kill your carriage return problem, if not you could try:

```
autocmd BufWritePre * g/[^"]\n/join
```

I've had the first autocommand for a long time and it works well.

The second one I've not tested.

Comment: Having an autocommand like this is a good idea. You might want to restrict based on  filetype, though. Some formats (e.g. markdown) give trailing whitespace a meaning.

Comment: of course, didn't think of markdown